# Getting error in extended operation for change password - [LDAP: error code 2 - unsupported extended operation]; remaining name ''

Tags: ldap

I want to reset password of any user in Sun one LDAP( or for that matter any other LDAP ) using extended operation. For the same, I have done following:

I have written two classes as follows:

PasswordExtendedRequest which implements ExtendedRequest AND

PasswordExtendedResponse which implements ExtendedResponse

I am using OID "1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.11.1" inside **PasswordExtendedRequest**

Following is code for extended operation

```
ExtendedRequest er = new PasswordExtendedRequest(<userName>,<password>);
ExtendedResponse extRes = (ExtendedResponse)ctx.extendedOperation(er);
```

But I am getting following error after execution and getResponseControls() is also returning NULL.
**javax.naming.CommunicationException: [LDAP: error code 2 - unsupported extended operation]; remaining name ''**

From the error it looks like that LDAP I am using, is not supporting this extended operation. What should I do with LDAP to support this reset password extended operation?

Let me know I am doing anything wrong or missing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the  Sun one LDAP server implementation you are using does not support the "1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.11.1" extension. To implement this extension would require the LDAP server administrator to implement it. (if the Sun One LDAP server CAN even support it)

Extensions are extensions beyond LDAP and may or may not be available on any given LDAP server.

You should be able to identify the support for the extension by querying the rootDSE and checking if the OID is present within the supportedExtension attribute.
-jim